# How to phrase a HTML return to get a certain string while ignoring other data

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a webpage that sends back a rather long string, most of which I don't need. I need a way to trim this without taking out data I need, counting places isn't an option as the return can vary.

The return looks like:

```
GET /New%20Messenger&subtitle=Test_1:Test_2 HTTP/1.1
```

Everything before `Test_1:Test_2` will be different, therefore I can't just delete that bit.

I only need that part `Test_1:Test_2` however, or just if it's simpler everything from the `=` but before the `HTTP/1.1`.

I could add something before the string I need but unsure how I'd go about pulling the string from that as well.

The data is returned to my server written in C#. I can post some code, but don't see how it'd be helpful as it's just a basic server.

Comment: str.split("subtitle=")[1].split("&")[0]

Comment: What logical rule determines that *Test_1:Test_2* is the data to fetch?  You need to add more example inputs & desired outputs.  Do you want to parse this in JavaScript or C#?

Comment: Test_1:Test_2 are just an example, the actual data will vary most likely with no underscores, but the ':' part will remain as I'm splitting that into separate strings. I'm doing this in c#. 

The split seems to return everything after including the HTTP/1.1, which is why I was thinking split would be impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your goal is to extract only this information (`Test_1:Test_2`) from next string 
`GET /New%20Messenger&subtitle=Test_1:Test_2 HTTP/1.1`.You can try to use Regex for this purpose.

```
string returnedString = "GET /New%20Messenger&subtitle=Test_1:Test_2 HTTP/1.1"
Regex exp = new Regex(@"(?<==)(.*)(?=\s)");
Match match = exp.Match(returnedString);
    if(match.Success){
       //Do something with match.Value. For example print output in console.
       Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
```

Try to figure out with this RegExp.This [link](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1061) will be helpful for you.

Comment: This is close, I still get "=1234:55 HTTP/1.1" as my return. I could do a simple delete to get rid of the =, however the HTTP/1.1 part can be x amount of spaces out.

Comment: Got the full result I wanted with "(?<==)(.*)(?=\s)( )". Thanks for your time!